# Can I activate the rubber duck even if it is not April 1st?

Tags: support, april-fools

I'd like to show the rubber duck to a friend, but it's gone. All the rubber-duck-related answers just tell how to get it back once you already clicked on "I hate this duck", but is there a way to reactivate it on let's say December 6th?

[image]

I am aware that this was an April fool on 01.04.2018. However, as Google has its [Google Doodles Archive](https://www.google.com/doodles), I'd enjoy having something like this here on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: That was an April fools gag for [2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/april-fools/info). It wasn't really meant to be permanent...

Comment: Related on MSE: [Will quack overflow be accessible after the 1st?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308618/241919)

Comment: @SurajRao I know that. However, as Google has its Google Doodles Archive https://www.google.com/doodles, I'd enjoy having something like this here :)

Comment: Well maybe some day Stack Overflow is about what we enjoy, but right now... it really isn't.

Comment: Google Doodles are selfcontained, though, one of the great things about the Stack Overflow April Fools jokes is that they're integrated into the site (such as the ultra dark mode and the time machine) which means they'll likely break over time. You can try your luck on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180401051652/https://stackoverflow.com/), though, most April 1st things are eternalized there.

Comment: I still think that with a few years of groovy coding and machine learning we'll either have something even more worthwhile than traditional Rubber Duck Debugging here or have programmed a computer to think that humans exist only to torture computers and should be exterminated by nuclear fire.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access it via a mirror at https://unikong.github.io/quackoverflow/ ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308630/349538)).

Comment: The one user uniquely qualified to answer this question! :)